# setting up ecomdev install error 'host is not set for base url'

Tags: magento-1, installation, testing, unit-tests, ecomdev-phpunit

I am trying to install ecomdevs' unit testing with my copy of magento. I have added the folders manually to the relevant directories and added the below in `app/etc/local.xml.phpunit`

```
<default>
    <web>
        ...
        <secure>
            <base_url>http://siteName.local</base_url><!--also tried localhost and siteName.local-->
        <secure>
        <unsecure>
            <base_url>http://siteName.local</base_url><!--also tried localhost and siteName.local-->
        <unsecure>
        ...
    </web>
</default>
```

When I go to the command line in the root folder of my site and enter `phpunit` I get a fatal error returned

> Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Cannot run controller test, because the host is not set for base url

I know I'm missing something obvious but ive been looking at this problem for far to long, why am I getting this error? (I'm following [this guide](http://bit.ly/mR6uKc))

Comment: Your base urls are missing the trailing slash. Maybe that's the problem, I could always use .local domains without trouble.

Comment: I'd add that it's probably better to use http://www.somesite.local/ given cookie handling issues that may affect all versions of magento per @alan-kent : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64619/magento-on-localhost-links-not-working/64623#64623

At least, you can expect more consistent behavior when you modify your local hosts file to use local domains that have three-part names based on the results of those tests.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post my comment as an answer too: Your base urls are missing the trailing slash. Maybe that's the problem, I could always use .local domains without trouble.

Also, EcomDev_PhpUnit comes with a setup shell script that you can use to set the base URL and other things (but the magento-config action basically writes to local.xml.phpunit):

```
cd shell
php -f ecomdev-phpunit.php -- -a magento-config --base-url http://sitename.local/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while ago and I think inserting a record into core_config_data table in tests database helped. Something like:

`INSERT INTO core_config_data SET path = 'web/unsecure/base_url', value='http://localhost/magento/';`

Answer (score -3):

Shouldn't you put those changes in app/etc/local.xml so they get read into Magento directly? The .phpunit file is not a file that affects Magento unless you've customized the code.

Comment: It is the file that is used by EcomDev_PHPUnit for running tests.